# How to determine $n$ values of Abs[2^n - 51] is a prime number?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that it is required to find the values of $n$ such that `Abs[2^n - 51]` is a prime number. It is easy to determine that the first few values are $\{2,3,5,6,...\}_{n\geq 0}$. How can *Mathematica* code be written to determine further values?

Comment: `Select[Table[{n, Abs[2^n - 51]}, {n, 0, 100}], PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &][[All,
   1]]` gives such numbers up to $n=100$

Comment: I understand how this works up to a point. That point is: What does the `PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &][[All, 1]]` portion do? `PrimeQ` verifies the prime value, but the rest?

Comment: First you make a `Table` that consists of pairs `{n,Abs[2^n-51}`, then you need to select pairs where second half is prime - `PrimeQ[#[[2]]]`. Now you still have a list of pairs - effectively a matrix, you need only first column, but all rows, this is what [[All,1]] does. You probably want to read about pure functions and slots. It will help if you run every command separately.

Comment: @BlacKow Thanks for the help and explanations.

Comment: `Select[Range[100], PrimeQ[2^# - 51] &]`

Comment: `Pick[#, PrimeQ[2^# - 51]] &@Range[1000]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three solutions provided in comments are all perfectly viable, and their performance is comparable as well:

```
nmax = 3000;
Select[Table[{n, Abs[2^n - 51]}, {n, 0, 3000}], 
       PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming
Select[Range[3000], PrimeQ[2^# - 51] &]; // RepeatedTiming
Pick[#, PrimeQ[2^# - 51]] &@Range[3000]; // RepeatedTiming
Cases[Range[nmax], x_ /; PrimeQ[2^x - 51]]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out:
 {1.66, Null}
 {1.64, Null}
 {1.65, Null}
 {1.70, Null}
*)
```

However, in my opinion Bob Hanlon's approach using `Select` or RunnyKine's approach using `Cases` are the cleanest and most readable, and they also have the advantage of being *automatically parallelizable*. `Parallelize` must recognize that the test specified can be run in parallel on the first argument. This is quite convenient:

```
Parallelize@
    Select[Table[{n, Abs[2^n - 51]}, {n, 0, nmax}], 
           PrimeQ[#[[2]]] &][[All, 1]]; // RepeatedTiming

Parallelize@ Select[Range[nmax], PrimeQ[2^# - 51] &]; // RepeatedTiming

Parallelize[Pick[#, PrimeQ[2^# - 51]] &@Range[nmax]]; // RepeatedTiming

Parallelize@Cases[Range[nmax], x_ /; PrimeQ[2^x - 51]]; // RepeatedTiming

(*Out:
 {1.722, Null}
 {1.1, Null}
 {1.676, Null}
 {1.1, Null}
*)
```

For instance, the timing of the "parallel `Select`" is comparable to manual parallelization:

```
Extract[
 range = Range[nmax], 
 Position[ParallelMap[PrimeQ[2^# - 51] &, range], True]
]; // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {1.1, Null} *)
```

Comment: On my computer this is actually the fastest: `Cases[Range@3000, x_ /; PrimeQ[2^x - 51]]`, strangely enough. And can also be `Parallelize`d.

Comment: @RunnyKine Good point about the `Cases` option being parallelizable. I added it to the answer, but I could not see a time advantage to it on my system (see timings, on Win7-64 using MMA 10.4).

Comment: On my system (Win 10 MMA 10.4) it's just slightly faster that `Select`: 1.70 vs 1.73 seconds. Same for the `Parallelize`d versions: 0.5 vs 0.53 seconds.